# How many RAM Hardfaults is too many?

Tags: memory

Trying to play BF3, sometimes seemingly randomly, it will start lagging.

I assumed despite 4GB of RAM, it might be hitting its max.

I just however noticed a lot of RAM Hardfaults. Is this a lot, or normal?

Would it affect my game, or is it lack of RAM?

Note: the game is loading up at this point, so is not at its near max. Which I think runs at 90+% at all times when plying bf3.

[image]

Comment: As it was once explained to me simply. the system is "fault based" :-)  The memory system is designed to work like that. Hard faults do not indicate actual paging to disk, because there are many different ways that paging occurs.  It is just shifting stuff around, pushing stuff out of ram , and (hopefully) going on. http://superuser.com/questions/314184/do-i-need-to-worry-about-hard-faults.  I really doubt that a large increase in ram would help you, but if you have/want a lot of other junk running, it might not hurt to close some of it, or get more ram. like say a few of those chrome tabs?

Comment: Believe it or not, (i had already researched this), Chrome.exe represents all the different addons, not tabs. I have disabled the major ones, like adblock. Unfortuantely the game itself requires 2 addons of terrible computation (battlelog addon) to run the game. So that is always running in the background. Why the game isnt self contained I dont know. Plus, Chrome clearly wanted to hide down the list how much the whole of chrome actually uses. Very heavy. I disabled all services and Apps that W7 does not need. Thanks though for your answer. I did a memory check and it came up 100% clear. :)

Comment: Seeing that you are in windows 7, you can scavange up some extra memory by disabling the "superfetch" service. While the superfetch ram use would also be freed as needed, it would probably give you a testing of what it would be like if a "little" more ram was added to the system.  Strangely I have 8G and cant seem to even GET the 64bit system to make use of more than like 3G :-) But then I noticed some of the other programs people are using Like chrome, that can ask for large ammounts, and did manage to get enough programs and tabs open to similate it.

Comment: I'll have a look into "superfetch" when I get home :) You should put this good info as an answer ! :D